# 'min_active_rowversion' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization

I was trying to run the sample "Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express" from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx but this error kept appearing

```
Exception.Message
```

> Failed to Execute Provider Command 'SelectNewTimestampCommand'. The transaction
>   was rolled back. Ensure that the command syntax is correct and check the inner exception for any store-specific errors.

```
Exception.InnerException
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'min_active_rowversion' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, Run
>   Behavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehav
>   ior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult
>    result)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeHandler.GetLocalTimestamp(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction)

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition_(x64) and Visual Studio 2012.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Updated**

Finally, after a lot of searching and digging, I found the solution: when I executed query `SELECT @@VERSION`, it shown that my version is SQL Server 2005 SP1 although I'm using SQL Server 2014. So I re-installed it then it worked perfectly.

Comment: what is  the complete query you are executing?

Comment: actually there is no built query in the sample